# How to receiving data when the iOS app is in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, background-process

I have iOS app developers in Xamarin.Forms. I want to receive the request (from server) and want to execute it in iOS app, when it is in minimized / background mode. I have already played with Background Modes option available in Info.plist like "Audio, Airplay and Picture in Picture", "Voice over IP", "Background fetch", "Background Processing" but it didn't work for me.

If anyone have ideas above for this, then Kindly help me to resolve.

Thanks in advance,

Vivek

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you, you'll need to give more information than that, like what are you trying to achieve? and you'll need to give the exact example, and perhaps show what you've tried doing so far

Comment: My actual problem is, iOS application is not able to run the code when app is in background, it goes into pause state, and when I heads the app to foreground it resumes the code execution. So I don't want to interrupt my incoming request (from server) and its execution when app is in minimized mode.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at [Performing Tasks During DidEnterBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks#performing-tasks-during-didenterbackground) .

In addition to making a long-running task background-safe, registration can be used to kick off tasks as an application is being put in the background. iOS provides an event method in the AppDelegate class called `DidEnterBackground` that can be used to save application state, save user data, and encrypt sensitive content before an application enters the background. An application has approximately five seconds to return from this method or it will get terminated. Therefore, cleanup tasks that might take more than five seconds to complete can be called from inside the `DidEnterBackground` method. These tasks must be invoked on a separate thread.

The process is nearly identical to that of registering a long-running task. The following code snippet illustrates this in action:

```
public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application) {
  nint taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask( () => {});
  new Task ( () => {
    DoWork();
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskID);
  }).Start();
}
```

You can do something in `DoWork` method . By the way , I think apple not recommanding to work as a service to receive data . Generally , this background task is designed to deal with not finished transfering data , such as download or upload data .

Comment: Jiang: Thanks for your input but, I don't want to process any data when app is going to minimized. My app is already minimized, and I want to process the requests that are come from server.
For example, my app is already minimized and server is sending the request message to the app and I want to receive and execute that request.

Comment: @VivekPatel Okey , I think app from installed to minimized, it should invoke `DidEnterBackground` at least first .

Comment: My app is having messaging and calling functionality. When app is in background mode and some one send the message or do the call, I want to send that message/calling request from my cloud server to the iOS app and want to notify the user by local notification. So how can I achieve this? You have any idea?

Comment: @VivekPatel It depends on message server whehter keep connection with 
mobile application . The premise is that you need such a message server to maintain communication with mobile application , this is not only done by the client itself. Just having a suggestion that you can create a long time connection with message server first .Then when in background not closing the connection . When message coming , application will recceive the message . From my shared code , you can keep the connection be alive after entering background .