# how to play sound if app is in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I have the iOS application developed in the Xamarin.Forms. How can I play the sound when app is in minimized mode?

Could someone please give any hint or example of how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class musicPlayer {
    public static var instance = musicPlayer()
    var player = AVPlayer()

    func initPlayer(url : String) {
        guard let url = URL.init(string: url) else { return }
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
        playAudioBackground()
    }

    func playAudioBackground() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func pause(){
        player.pause()
    }

    func play() {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: You also need to enable "audio" in UIBackgroundModes.

Comment: I want to play the custom notification sound when app is already in minimized mode.

Comment: For this you need VOIP push notification service enable and when call arrives the backend will fire notification  to you phone udid and than you can set custom sound for notifcation.

Comment: can you guide me, how to set VOIP push notification?

Answer (score 3):

In **Xamarin iOS** ,you need to set it up in the Capabilities of the project to enable the background mode in `info.plist` first .

[image]

Then you need to add follow code in `AppDelegate.cs` :

```
public bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

    AVAudioSession session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
    session.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.Playback);
    session.SetActive(true);

    return true;
}
```

Then you can create a sample audio player by **AVPlayer** :

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public AVAudioPlayer player;
    public float MusicVolume
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = 0.5f;

    public bool MusicOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    } = true;

    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    partial void UIButtonPlay_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Console.WriteLine("play");
        PlayMusic();
    }


    public void PlayMusic()
    {
        NSUrl songURL;
        if (!MusicOn) return;
        //Song url from your local Resource  
        songURL = new NSUrl("Sounds/Alan_Walker.mp3");
        NSError err;
        player = new AVAudioPlayer(songURL, "Song", out err);
        player.Volume = MusicVolume;
        player.FinishedPlaying += delegate {
            // backgroundMusic.Dispose();  
            player = null;
        };
        //Background Music play  
        player.Play();
    }

    partial void UIButtonStop_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        Console.WriteLine("stop");
        player.Stop();
    }

    public override void RemoteControlReceived(UIEvent theEvent)
    {
        base.RemoteControlReceived(theEvent);
        Console.WriteLine("RemoteControlReceived");
        switch (theEvent.Subtype)
        {
            case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay:
                //play the music
                Console.WriteLine("Remote Play"); player.Play();
                break;

            case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause:
                //pause the music
                Console.WriteLine("Remote Stop"); player.Stop();
                break;

            case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlNextTrack:
                //play next one 
                break;

            case UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPreviousTrack:
                //play last one 
                break;
            dafault:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Last , you can add background Control when `DidEnterBackground` and `DidBecomeActive` . From iOS 13 , these lifecycle methond has been moved from `AppDelegate` to `SceneDelegate`.

```
public class SceneDelegate : UIResponder, IUIWindowSceneDelegate
{

    [Export("window")]
    public UIWindow Window { get; set; }

    [Export("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
    public void WillConnect(UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
    {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see UIApplicationDelegate `GetConfiguration` instead).
    }

    [Export("sceneDidDisconnect:")]
    public void DidDisconnect(UIScene scene)
    {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see UIApplicationDelegate `DidDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    [Export("sceneDidBecomeActive:")]
    public void DidBecomeActive(UIScene scene)
    {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
    }

    [Export("sceneWillResignActive:")]
    public void WillResignActive(UIScene scene)
    {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    [Export("sceneWillEnterForeground:")]
    public void WillEnterForeground(UIScene scene)
    {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    [Export("sceneDidEnterBackground:")]
    public void DidEnterBackground(UIScene scene)
    {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
        SetLockInfo();
    }
    public void SetLockInfo()
    {
        //NSMutableDictionary songInfo = new NSMutableDictionary();
        MPNowPlayingInfo playInfo = new MPNowPlayingInfo();
        //image
        MPMediaItemArtwork albumArt = new MPMediaItemArtwork(new UIImage());
        playInfo.Artwork = albumArt;
        //title
        playInfo.Title = "your song name";
        //singer
        playInfo.Artist = "singer name";
        //rate
        playInfo.PlaybackRate = 1.0;
        //current time
        playInfo.ElapsedPlaybackTime = 0;
        //durtaion
        playInfo.PlaybackDuration = 2.35; // the durtaion of the song
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter.NowPlaying = playInfo;

    }
}
```

When entering to background , you need to pass current audio info to **MPNowPlayingInfoCenter** .

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my app is not a music app even I don't want to display the player on lock screen. I am having calling app, so whenever incoming call request arrives and in minimized/background mode I want to play the call ringing sound.

Comment: @VivekPatel Okey , you can have a look at this discussion . I think you need to listen receive data when enter to background .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883276/how-to-receiving-data-when-the-ios-app-is-in-background-mode/60925863#60925863

Comment: On that post I have posted the question, but not get the solution that I want.

Comment: @VivekPatel Okey , your question is not only related to mobile application . Much more works need message server to support that . The mobile application just need to keep the connection with Message server . I think there is no easy way to do sample things only in mobile application can implement that , you should know that first .